# How do you run programs through TextWrangler?

Tags: c++, textwrangler

I have just started to get experiment with C++ on my MacBook Pro, and am **very** new to it all.  Through research, a few different people have suggested to use TextWrangler for writing the code.  I have put together some of the code that the beginning of a tutorial has given me, but I am now unsure how to run it through TextWrangler.  I know that you are supposed to compile it first, but that is mostly where I'm stuck.  I have downloaded Xcode so I have gcc, but I don't know where to go from there.  And after I have compiled it, is there a simple way to run the file?  Like I said, I am **very** new to all of this and may be looking at it in the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

TextWrangler is only a text editor, you still need a compiler to compile your code and then you need to run your code.

Xcode (which is an IDE) does all that for you so the confusion is understandable.

for now opening a terminal and doing `g++ filename.cpp` to compile and `./a.out` to run your program will get you going. But you really have to learn to use a IDE or how to write a makefile.